# Unable to render color css property in PDF export using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Tried to export html page in PDF using puppeteer library, however **color** css property not rendering in PDF.

Added below code in html

```
<style>
    html {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
    @media print {
        .highlightTxt {
            color: #f79747;
        }
    }
</style>
```

below code in js

```
await page.pdf({ path: `./download/${filename}`, format: 'A4', landscape: false, printBackground: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Added below and it is working fine.

```
html {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
@media print {
    .highlightTxt {
        color: #f79747 !important;
    }
}
```